# Python save list and read data from file

Tags: python

Basically I would like to save a list to python and then when the program starts I would like to retrieve the data from the file and put it back into the list.

 
So far this is the code I am using

```
mylist = pickle.load("save.txt")
...
saveToList = (name, data)
mylist.append(saveList)
import pickle
pickle.dump(mylist, "save.txt")
```

But it just returns the following error: TypeError: file must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a file object, not just a file name. Try this for saving:

```
pickle.dump(mylist, open("save.txt", "wb"))
```

or better, to guarantee the file is closed properly:

```
with open("save.txt", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(mylist, f)
```

and then this for loading:

```
with open("save.txt", "rb") as f:
    mylist = pickle.load(f)
```

Also, I suggest a different extension from `.txt`, like maybe `.dat`, because the contents is not plain text.

Comment: I get TypeError: Function takes at most 1 positional arguments (2 given)

Comment: @DarkchiliSlayer Oops, fixed

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("save.txt", "w") as f:
    pickle.dump(f, mylist)
```

Refer to python pickle documentation for usage.

Answer (score 1):

pickle.dump accept file object as argument instead of filename string

```
pickle.dump(mylist, open("save.txt", "wb"))
```